# iOS MDM: How to know whether the applied policies(restriction) and configurations are complaint?

Tags: java, ios, mdm

I am done with iOS MDM enrollment as well as commands like DeviceInformation, DeviceLock and applying policies(restriction).

I want to check at server side whether the policies(restrictions) and configurations that I pushed are applied correctly or not?

e.g. : If I had set passcode policy with certain restriction, and I want to know whether user has set it correctly according to passcode policy applied.

Similarly, I have to test other restrictions and configurations, whether they applies correctly or not? So that I will maintain state of that device whether it is compliant or not?

So, Is there any way to know this? Or any command with which I will get to know applied restrictions and configurations on device?

Hope my question is clear to understand..

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command (**ProfileList**) to query for installed configuration profiles. This way you can check whether they were installed or not.

There is alway s a command (**Restrictions**). It will return the list of all applied restrictions (both globals and configured through profiles).

And there is a command (**SecurityInfo**). It will return whether passcode a present and compliant with profiles.

Comment: Thanks Victor! This was exactly what i was searching for. Now, I want to send multiple commands like **Restrictions** and **SecurityInfo** using single plist file. So, is there any way to do this?

Comment: No. You can send commands only one at the time. However, nothing prevents you to do them sequentially (right after each other).

Comment: Thanks Victor for such a nice help!